# Error importing gdal while using readthedocs

Tags: python

I am getting the foll. error in a project importing gdal, while trying to use readthedocs:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-OdYCI1/gdal/setup.py", line 196, in finalize_options
    self.gdaldir = self.get_gdal_config('prefix')
  File "/tmp/pip-build-OdYCI1/gdal/setup.py", line 176, in get_gdal_config
    return fetch_config(option)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-OdYCI1/gdal/setup.py", line 129, in fetch_config
    raise gdal_config_error, e""")
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
__main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-OdYCI1/gdal/

How can I fix this?